# Improving computation speed of a nested loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I have this loop that I tried to improve as much as possible, sadly, I don't know how to make it better.

Do you have any idea of improvement?

```
#partial is a data frame that look like this
partial = data.frame(
partial.regex = c("european construction industry federation",
" zentralverband des deutschen baugewerbes",
"hauptverband der deutschen bauindustrie",
"1 1 drillisch ag 439568220616 04"))

> summary(partial)
 partial.name          regex            full.name        
 Length:13202       Length:13202       Length:13202      
 Class :character   Class :character   Class :character  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character

#full is also a df
full = data.frame(
full.name = c("International Lead Association (ILA)", "Airborne Wind Europe", "Sazka Group a.s",
regex = c("international lead association (ila)", "airborne wind europe", "sazka group a.s.")
> summary(full)
  full.name            regex          
 Length:9779        Length:9779       
 Class :character   Class :character  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character
```

And here comes the loop. Sorry if this is dumb I am a real beginner !

```
for(y in 1:dim(partial)[1]){
  a = 0
  b = ""
  for(i in 1:dim(full)[1]){
    
    vec = c(partial$regex[y], full$regex[i])

  

if(length(Reduce(`intersect`,stri_extract_all_regex(vec,"\\w+"))) > a){
      a = length(Reduce(`intersect`,stri_extract_all_regex(vec,"\\w+")))
      partial$full[y] = full$full.name[i]
    }
    
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for all the help you can give me!

Best regards,

PS :
partial.csv = https://github.com/JMcrocs/MeetingMEPs/blob/main/partial.csv

full.csv = https://github.com/JMcrocs/MeetingMEPs/blob/main/full.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R option using ´outer`+`max.col`

```
partial$full <- full$full.name[
  max.col(
    lengths(outer(
      regmatches(partial$partial.regex, gregexpr("\\w+", partial$partial.regex)),
      regmatches(full$regex, gregexpr("\\w+", full$regex)),
      FUN = Vectorize(intersect)
    )),
    ties.method = "first"
  )
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is 3x faster! I still have a lot to learn